# Compiling individual project files rather than whole project?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, build, compilation

I'm running Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi 4 and I am looking to make changes to open source code. The project is quite large and comes with a Makefile. I am making changes to the source code using Geany. I then run the Makefile again which I believe compiles every file within the project. This takes quite a long time. So for example if I wish to insert a print statement into a function to see what is going on do I have to recompile the whole project? There has to be a more efficient way to debug C++ code than this.

Throughout my degree I have taken a few programming classes but none of these have been Linux based and all coursework has been self contained within an IDE. I also suspect that my many of my approaches may not be typical or optimal programming behaviours. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

EDIT - Including make file:

```
ifndef CONFIG
    CONFIG=Release
endif

ifndef LIBDIR
    LIBDIR=/usr/lib/
endif

DPKG := $(shell dpkg-buildflags --version 2> /dev/null)

ifdef DPKG
    DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS = hardening=+all
    SDEBCXXFLAGS := $(shell dpkg-buildflags --get CXXFLAGS)
    SDEBLDFLAGS := $(shell dpkg-buildflags --get LDFLAGS)

    DEB_BUILD_MAINT_OPTIONS=hardening=+bindnow
    PDEBCXXFLAGS := $(shell dpkg-buildflags --get CXXFLAGS)
    PDEBLDFLAGS := $(shell dpkg-buildflags --get LDFLAGS)
endif

MACHINE := $(shell sh -c 'uname -m 2> /dev/null || echo not')
ifneq (,$(findstring aarch,$(MACHINE)))
    SIMDFLAGS := -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53
else
ifneq (,$(findstring arm,$(MACHINE)))
    SIMDFLAGS := -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a53 -mfpu=neon-fp-armv8 -mfloat-abi=hard
else
    SIMDFLAGS := -msse2
endif
endif

PROGRAM = helm
BIN     = $(DESTDIR)/usr/bin
BINFILE = $(BIN)/$(PROGRAM)
LV2     = $(DESTDIR)/$(LIBDIR)/lv2/$(PROGRAM).lv2
VSTDIR  = $(DESTDIR)/$(LIBDIR)/lxvst
VST     = $(VSTDIR)/$(PROGRAM).so
SYSDATA = $(DESTDIR)/usr/share/$(PROGRAM)
IMAGES  = $(SYSDATA)/icons
PATCHES = $(SYSDATA)/patches
MAN     = $(DESTDIR)/usr/share/man/man1/
CHANGES = $(DESTDIR)/usr/share/doc/$(PROGRAM)/
DESKTOP = $(DESTDIR)/usr/share/applications/

ICONS   = $(DESTDIR)/usr/share/icons/hicolor/
ICON16  = images/helm_icon_16_1x.png
ICON22  = images/helm_icon_22_1x.png
ICON24  = images/helm_icon_24_1x.png
ICON32  = images/helm_icon_32_1x.png
ICON48  = images/helm_icon_48_1x.png
ICON64  = images/helm_icon_32_2x.png
ICON128 = images/helm_icon_128_1x.png
ICON256 = images/helm_icon_256_1x.png

ICONDEST16 = $(ICONS)/16x16/apps
ICONDEST22 = $(ICONS)/22x22/apps
ICONDEST24 = $(ICONS)/24x24/apps
ICONDEST32 = $(ICONS)/32x32/apps
ICONDEST48 = $(ICONS)/48x48/apps
ICONDEST64 = $(ICONS)/64x64/apps
ICONDEST128 = $(ICONS)/128x128/apps
ICONDEST256 = $(ICONS)/256x256/apps

all: standalone lv2 vst

install_icons:
    install -d $(ICONDEST16) $(ICONDEST22) $(ICONDEST24) $(ICONDEST32)
    install -d $(ICONDEST48) $(ICONDEST64) $(ICONDEST128) $(ICONDEST256)
    cp $(ICON16) $(ICONDEST16)/$(PROGRAM).png
    cp $(ICON22) $(ICONDEST22)/$(PROGRAM).png
    cp $(ICON24) $(ICONDEST24)/$(PROGRAM).png
    cp $(ICON32) $(ICONDEST32)/$(PROGRAM).png
    cp $(ICON48) $(ICONDEST48)/$(PROGRAM).png
    cp $(ICON64) $(ICONDEST64)/$(PROGRAM).png
    cp $(ICON128) $(ICONDEST128)/$(PROGRAM).png
    cp $(ICON256) $(ICONDEST256)/$(PROGRAM).png

standalone:
    $(MAKE) -d -C standalone/builds/linux CONFIG=$(CONFIG) DEBCXXFLAGS="$(SDEBCXXFLAGS)" DEBLDFLAGS="$(SDEBLDFLAGS)" SIMDFLAGS="$(SIMDFLAGS)"

lv2:
    $(MAKE) -C builds/linux/LV2 CONFIG=$(CONFIG) DEBCXXFLAGS="$(PDEBCXXFLAGS)" DEBLDFLAGS="$(PDEBLDFLAGS)" SIMDFLAGS="$(SIMDFLAGS)"

vst:
    $(MAKE) -C builds/linux/VST CONFIG=$(CONFIG) DEBCXXFLAGS="$(PDEBCXXFLAGS)" DEBLDFLAGS="$(PDEBLDFLAGS)" SIMDFLAGS="$(SIMDFLAGS)"

clean:
    $(MAKE) clean -C standalone/builds/linux CONFIG=$(CONFIG)
    $(MAKE) clean -C builds/linux/LV2 CONFIG=$(CONFIG)
    $(MAKE) clean -C builds/linux/VST CONFIG=$(CONFIG)

install_patches:
    rm -rf $(PATCHES)
    install -d $(PATCHES)
    cp -rf patches/* $(PATCHES)

install_standalone: standalone install_patches install_icons
    install -d $(BIN) $(IMAGES) $(MAN) $(CHANGES) $(DESKTOP)
    install standalone/builds/linux/build/$(PROGRAM) $(BIN)
    install -m644 standalone/helm.desktop $(DESKTOP)/helm.desktop
    install -m644 images/* $(IMAGES)
    cp changelog changes
    gzip -n -9 changelog
    mv changes changelog
    mv changelog.gz $(CHANGES)/changelog.gz
    cp docs/helm.1.gz $(MAN)

install_lv2: lv2 install_patches
    install -d $(PATCHES) $(LV2)
    install -m644 builds/linux/LV2/helm.lv2/* $(LV2)
    cp -rf patches/* $(PATCHES)

install_vst: vst install_patches
    install -d $(PATCHES) $(VSTDIR)
    install builds/linux/VST/build/helm.so $(VST)
    cp -rf patches/* $(PATCHES)

thank_you:
ifdef PAID
    install -d $(PATCHES)
    cp docs/thank_you.txt $(PATCHES)
endif

install: install_standalone install_vst install_lv2 thank_you

dist:
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)
    mkdir $(PROGRAM)
    -cp -rf * $(PROGRAM)/
    $(MAKE) clean -C $(PROGRAM) CONFIG=Release
    $(MAKE) clean -C $(PROGRAM) CONFIG=Debug
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/.git
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/JUCE/extras
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/JUCE/examples
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/builds/osx
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/builds/vs12
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/builds/vs15
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/standalone/builds/osx
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/standalone/builds/vs12
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)/standalone/builds/vs15
    tar -cvzf $(PROGRAM).tar.gz $(PROGRAM)
    rm -rf $(PROGRAM)

uninstall:
    rm -rf $(LV2)
    rm -rf $(VST)
    rm -rf $(SYSDATA)
    rm -rf $(BINFILE)
    rm $(ICONDEST16)/$(PROGRAM).png
    rm $(ICONDEST22)/$(PROGRAM).png
    rm $(ICONDEST24)/$(PROGRAM).png
    rm $(ICONDEST32)/$(PROGRAM).png
    rm $(ICONDEST48)/$(PROGRAM).png
    rm $(ICONDEST64)/$(PROGRAM).png
    rm $(ICONDEST128)/$(PROGRAM).png
    rm $(ICONDEST256)/$(PROGRAM).png

.PHONY: standalone
```

Comment: A properly constructed makefile will only recompile the files that have changed. Add the the makefile to the question with an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60745549/edit), add the `make` tag, and I'm sure one of the make-gurus here can help you set up or optimize the makefile.

Comment: This doesn't look like it is specifically a C++ question but instead a make question.
You can run 
$ make -d 
To see what make is doing.

If you still think it is not doing the correct thing then ask again with a specific question under the tag make.

Comment: Thanks for both your answers. The makefile I am executing is for an open source synthesizer called helm. I'm assuming a makefile such as this is for a once off setup and is not designed for editing the source code. Am I right in assuming that I will need to edit this makefile or even write my own? Is this the appropriate way to edit source code on Linux; make necessary changes - execute a makefile - repeat?

Comment: Which file do you wish to modify, how do you invoke Make (e.g. with `make standalone` or `make lv2` or `make` or what), and which executable file do you execute to see the new behavior?

Comment: @Beta I have been running `make standalone` followed by `sudo make install_standalone`. The files I wish to modify are just the helm .cpp files. I feel a bigger issue here is the general approach to debugging code on Linux without using an IDE which is something that I'm still unsure of and haven't been able to find a clear method or approach.

Comment: Does the unnecessary delay appear to be in the `make standalone` step, or the `sudo make install_standalone` step, or both? I see different problems in each.